# ERC1155 and ERC1155UriStorage Question

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, nft, erc-1155

For anyone who has worked with Open Zepp's ERC1155 and ERC155UriStorage.  Both of them have a _setURI function and a uri function (returns the token uri). 2 questions when using both of these contracts together...

1.)When using both is it..... `contract NFTContract is ERC1155URIStorage, ERC1155 {}`
In other words do you list both like this?

2.)How do I ensure the _setURI and uri functions are being called on the ERC1155URIstorage contract and not the ERC1155? Just make the one i want to override (ERC155) virtual and label the the contract I want to use for these functions (ERC155URIStrorage) with override?  Do I also have to reference the ERC1155URIStorage in this _setURI function when doing so or is the "override" enough?

Or do i have it all wrong? This is very possible too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ERC1155URIStorage`, it is already inheriting from `ERC1155`, so you do not need to inherit both in your contract. Just inherit from `ERC1155URIStorage` and you get what you need.
Your inheritance chain would look like `NFTContract -> ERC1155URIStorage -> ERC1155`, therefore, you are indirectly inheriting from `ERC1155`.

For Your function calls, they go up the chain and access the first function signature that exists.